# SQL language programming using decode in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

I have two parameters called START_DATE and END_DATE.

If the start date and end date are entered , i would like to use the TO_CHAR to convert to a different format and display  ":start_date - :end_date" both in the format 'MON DD, YYYY')

However, if the parameters are not entered i would like to use the TO_CHAR function to display information for the previous month i.e ( MAR 01, 2017- MAR 31,2017).

Here's the code below. Can someone identify my error and assist?

```
SELECT DECODE (TO_CHAR(:START_DATE, 'MON DD, YYYY',(trunc(trunc(sysdate,'MONTH')-1,'MONTH'))),'MON DD, YYYY')
   || ' - ' || DECODE (TO_CHAR(:END_DATE, 'MON DD, YYYY',(trunc(sysdate,'MONTH')-1)'MON DD, YYYY') BILLPERIOD
```

How do i write this in sql using the decode function?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Many product specific functions in your query.

Comment: What flavour of SQL do you use? Tag the question with that?

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL dbms.

Comment: I retried again , Is this more accurate:      SELECT DECODE (:START_DATE, NULL, TO_CHAR((trunc(trunc(sysdate,'MONTH')-1,'MONTH')),'MON DD, YYYY'), TO_CHAR (:START_DATE,'MON DD, YYYY'))|| ' - ' || DECODE (:END_DATE, NULL, TO_CHAR((trunc(sysdate,'MONTH')-1),'MON DD, YYYY'), TO_CHAR(:END_DATE,'MON DD, YYYY'))

Comment: @jarlh: are you sure? I could be wrong but I think this standard SQL e.g. the `||` operator for concatenation, `:` prefix for a parameter, etc. The only questionable syntax is `sysdate` (reserved word) but I think the intent is clear.

Comment: @onedaywhen, none of DECODE, TO_CHAR, TRUNC and SYSDATE is ANSI SQL. (And I'm lost here...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend you use a CASE statement instead. More control, more readable, cleaner, etc. In my humble opinion of course.

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    -- If one or both dates are NULL, revert to last month
    WHEN start_date IS NULL OR end_date IS NULL THEN
      to_char(trunc(trunc(sysdate,'MM')-1,'MM'), 'MON DD, YYYY') || ' - ' || to_char(trunc(sysdate,'MM')-1, 'MON DD, YYYY')
    WHEN start_date IS NOT NULL AND end_date IS NOT NULL AND
    (start_date < end_date) THEN
      to_char(start_date, 'MON DD, YYYY') || ' - ' || to_char(end_date, 'MON DD, YYYY')
    -- ** ALWAYS EXPECT THE UNEXPECTED!  **
    -- Like start_date >= end_date
    ELSE '**  DATE ERROR  **'
  END as billperiod
  FROM dual;
```

EDIT: Added a check for start_date must be < end_date.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `CASE` in your project try:

```
SELECT
  CASE START_DATE
    WHEN NULL THEN TO_CHAR(PREVIOUS_DATE, 'MON DD, YYYY')
    ELSE TO_CHAR(START_DATE, 'MON DD, YYYY')
    END || ','
  CASE END_DATE
    WHEN NULL THEN TO_CHAR(PREVIOUS_DATE, 'MON DD, YYYY')
    ELSE TO_CHAR(END_DATE, 'MON DD, YYYY')
    END "Formated Date"
FROM BILLPERIOD;
```

Comment: I am honestly not very comfortable with using CASE. I prefer DECODE at the moment until i learn more about CASE

Comment: Would this Decode work: SELECT DECODE (:START_DATE, NULL, TO_CHAR((trunc(trunc(sysdate,'MONTH')-1,'MONTH')),'MON DD, YYYY'), TO_CHAR (:START_DATE,'MON DD, YYYY'))|| ' - ' || DECODE (:END_DATE, NULL, TO_CHAR((trunc(sysdate,'MONTH')-1),'MON DD, YYYY'), TO_CHAR(:END_DATE,'MON DD, YYYY'))